# lstrip method does not produce what I want

Tags: python, binary

I am trying to convert decimal to binary number and remove the 0b on the left most side so I can work with 1's and 0's. I succeeded however, when the binary was actually 0. if you lstrip "0b" from "0b0" must be "0" right?

But there is no character inside. it's empty as you can see in the last line of output.

What is going on???

Source code:

```
value = [255, 255, 255, 0]
binary = [bin(x) for x in value]
binstring = [str(y) for y in binary]
purebin = []
for x in binstring:
     purebin.append(x.lstrip("0b"))
print(binary)
print(binstring)
print(purebin)
```

Output:

> ['0b11111111', '0b11111111', '0b11111111', '0b0']
>
> ['0b11111111', '0b11111111', '0b11111111', '0b0']
>
> ['11111111', '11111111', '11111111', '']

Answer (score 4):

You're misinterpreting how lstrip works. Here's the documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.lstrip

Basically, it takes off characters from the beginning *from the pool of chars given*, not just the first occurrences. However, what you're trying to do is pretty easy, just don't to lstrip but `x[2:]`.

P.S. There's no need for that intermediate `str` step. `bin` gives is as a string.

Answer (score 2):

Why not to take substring of them (instead of lstrip) ?

```
a = ['0b11111111', '0b11111111', '0b11111111', '0b0']
map(lambda e: e[2:], a)
Out[2]: ['11111111', '11111111', '11111111', '0']
```

Comment: the 4 decimal numbers will be taken as input. so it will be different everytime.

Answer (score 1):

@Maltysen has already given a good answer to the question. As an alternative, if you are not going to need the `0b`, you may as well skip the whole `bin()` and `str()` and just use `format`:

```
print [format(v, 'b') for v in value]
Out[6]: ['11111111', '11111111', '11111111', '0']
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what is happening is the 0's after the '0b' are being interpreted as white space and are being stripped.

You can see this in action if you call '0b00000'.lstrip('0b') which will return the empty string as well.

I recommend that you use the syntax '0b0'[2:] which will give you all the characters after the '0b'